# Rails Nested Attributes / inverse_of and STI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes, single-table-inheritance

I've been banging my head for a while on this one. The problem comes in when saving both a new referral (the parent object) and an appointment(child) at the same time. I've done similar with other nested objects but can't seem make it work with single table inheritance -- appointments table. For some reason inverse_of doesn't pass the id of the new referral to the appointment.

```
class Referral < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :appointments, class_name: 'Appointment::Base', inverse_of: :referral

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :appointments

end

class Appointment::Base < ActiveRecord::Base

  self.table_name = 'appointments'

  belongs_to :referral, inverse_of: :appointments

end
```

in the view

```
fields_for :appointments do |a|
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you solve this by now?

Answer (score 1):

What about using the `class_name` for `referral` in the `belongs_to` clause? Like this:

```
class Appointment::Base < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  belongs_to :referral, class_name: 'Referral', inverse_of: :appointments
end
```

Rails may be looking in the same namespace as `Base` (`Appointment`) for `Referral`